# Trying to pass arguments to java application

Tags: java, arguments

So I have a program with an updater and I've made a mistake before releasing it. I totally forgot about by-passing the update so the user can update it later.

Now I'm trying to fix it and I thought that creating an argument with "-no_patching" is the best solution to this.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        checkVersion();
        System.err.println("patching ON");
    } else if(args.toString().matches("-no_patching")) {
        System.err.println("patching OFF");
        launchApp();
    }
}
```

The thing is when i run the program with argument it runs for 1 second then it stops. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

args is array. You should do it like this:

```
for(String arg : args)
{
    if(arg.matches("-no_patching")){
        System.err.println("patching OFF");
        launchApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, i think this one has a bonus for future if i need to add more args, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the mistake at line `args.toString().matches("-no_patching")`.

That should be

```
else if(args[0].equals("-no_patching")){ // make sure args length is 1
            System.err.println("patching OFF");
            launchApp();
        }
```

`toString()` on `args` array wont give you contents.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match the `args` array instead of matching first argument from that array.

```
//this is not what you want
args.toString().matches("-no_patching")
```

You need to get first element from array and then do comparison :

```
args[0].equals("-no_patching")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, convert args to a List and use the contains method to see if there are any argument matches:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length == 0){
    checkVersion();
    System.err.println("patching ON");
    } else if(Arrays.asList(args).contains("-no_patching")){
        System.err.println("patching OFF");
        launchApp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i totally forgot about array thing... i guess I panicked a bit xD

```
else if(args[0].equals("-no_patching")){
   //do something
}
```

did the trick, Thank you!

Comment: accept one answer if it worked...this question is showing unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying an incorrect comparison in the ELSE IF

```
         else if(args.toString().matches("-no_patching"))
```

`args.toString()` would give some address value of the argument array args. If this is compared with your "-no_patching" argument it would definitely return FALSE.

Rather you can always compare like

```
         else if(args[0].toString().matches("-no_patching"))
```